# Swift Json Decoder, unable to decode nested objects array

Tags: json, swift, nested, jsondecoder

I have the following json which contains a user, and the positions they hold in office. I can decode the user disregarding the positions just fine, but when I try to decode the array of positions it fails. I have try making seperate enums for the position and using nested containers but nothing is working.

#### The JSON

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "jon",
        "id": "CE30BCF5-1335-4767-BD20-53F4EDE950CD",
        "title": "citizen",
        "username": "jon1",
        "positions": [
            {
                "id": "3332BC0E-0DA5-4B90-A836-4CF91B872B05",
                "name": "mayor",
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "id": "A5986304-A301-431E-92A2-5B53BA58FC89"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "governor",
                "id": "199761E2-BCC2-4EC9-93CE-C4E7F4FB9277",
                "jurisdiction": {
                    "id": "A5986304-A301-431E-92A2-5B53BA58FC89"
                }
            }
        ],
        "imageURLString": "jon1image",
        "civicRating": 5,
        "lastName": "samson"
    }
]
```

#### User Model

```
import Foundation

struct New_User: Codable {
    var id: UUID?
    var username: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var title: String
    var imageURLString: String?
    var civicRating: Double
    var positions: [New_Position] = []
    
    private enum UserKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case username
        case firstName
        case lastName
        case imageURLString
        case civicRating
        case title
        case positions
    }

}
extension New_User {
    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: UserKeys.self)
        
        self.id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        self.username = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .username)
        self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .title)
        self.firstName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        self.lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.imageURLString = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .imageURLString)
        self.civicRating = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .civicRating)
        self.positions = try container.decode([New_Position].self, forKey: .positions)

    }
}
```

#### Position Model

```
import Foundation

struct New_Position: Codable {
    var id: UUID?
    var jurisdiction: New_Jurisdiction
    var name: String
    
    private enum PositionKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case jurisdiction
        case name
    }
    
    
}
extension New_Position {
    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: PositionKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.jurisdiction = try container.decode(New_Jurisdiction.self, forKey: .jurisdiction)
        
        print("decoded")
    }
}
```

#### Jurisdiction Model

```
import Foundation

struct New_Jurisdiction: Codable {
    var id: UUID?
    var name: String
    var scope: String
    
    private enum JurisdictionKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case name
        case scope
    }
    
    
}
extension New_Jurisdiction {
    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: JurisdictionKeys.self)
        self.id = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.scope = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .scope)
        print("decoded")
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have also New_Jurisdiction struct?

Comment: I added the struct to the post

Comment: `id` is `String`.

Comment: `jurisdiction` isn’t having `name` and `scope` key. You shouldn’t add them into `CodingKey`. Also don’t use naming convention with `_` for class names. To debug exact error please add `do/catch` block while decoding.

Comment: Thank you, this solved it, and will do, updated naming convention and added debugging.